# Dispay Laravel blade content to user as is

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have laravel template.blade.php

```html
<div class="classone">
    <div class="classtwo">
        text
    </div>

    <div class="classtwo">
        text
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to display the code to the user as it is. Incluing new line and indents.

I was playing around with {!! !!}, nl2br(view()->render() even Blade::compileString but was unable to find an elegant solution. Everytime I was able to make it work it was difficult to maintain and every small change to the displayed code was laber intense.

I would like to ask for a suggeston how to display more complex html/css/js code to user. I though it will be fairy often topic but was unable to find anything which would help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried some things out. They may seem a little bit 'hacky' but I think they will suit your purpose. I used a freshly created Laravel 8 application as an example.

```php
<pre>{{ file_get_contents( resource_path('views/welcome.blade.php')) }}</pre>
```

[image: Blade file output]

You can use the `Blade` facade to compile your blade file to plain php if you want:

```php
<pre>{{ Blade::compileString(file_get_contents( resource_path('views/app.blade.php'))) }}</pre>
```

[image: PHP file output]

I put `<pre></pre>` tags around the output to show line breaks. It makes the code more readable.

Comment: Thank you for the offered solution. The only problem for me is relaing on the <pre> tag. By definition it have predeterming, fixed width and I need for the long lines to break to new line as they normally do. Is it possible to achive that by css. So the text keeps indented but breaks to new lines if too long?

For example if the code will be shown on small devices

Comment: Honestly no idea. Most of the time when people want to display code, they make the container around the `<pre></pre>` tag horizontal scrollable. This is also more readable in my opinion. Stackoverflow also does this, check the code examples in my answer ;)

Comment: I was quite a while you gave this answer. I gave it some reasearch and I still found it quite elegant solution so I accepted the answer. Sorry it took such a time.